# Freeradius 3 Accounting Max-All-Session is not sent to NAS

Tags: freeradius

I have a problem with freeradius 3 and mysql regarding the attribute "Max-All-Session"

It seems that the value "Max-All-Session" or rather the actual attribute "Session-Timeout" is never sent to the NAS when Mit is used in a profile attached to a user.

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Here is a debug output (freeradius -X)
- Body is to small for full log so please see link to pastebin.

https://pastebin.com/ipNyzdw4

```
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.16
Copyright (C) 1999-2017 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
Starting - reading configuration files ...
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.dhcp
including dictionary file /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.vqp
including dictionary file /etc/freeradius/3.0/dictionary
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/radiusd.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/proxy.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/clients.conf
including files in directory /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/radutmp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/eap
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/detail.log
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/replicate
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/ntlm_auth
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sql
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-config/sql/main/mysql/queries.conf
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/logintime
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/expiration
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sradutmp
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/attr_filter
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i got this to work, i had simply not included the counters in sites-available/default.

Under "authorize {" add the following:
        noresetcounter
        dailycounter
        monthlycounter

I hope this may help someone else.

//CN